# Prove: if for all $x,y \in A \subset \Bbb R$, $|x-y|<1$, then $\sup A-\inf A \le 1$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, supremum-and-infimum

Consider the fact: if for all $x,y \in A \subset \Bbb R$, $|x-y|<1$, then $\sup A-\inf A \le 1$.

It's not difficult to show that if one supposes that $
\sup A-\inf A > 1$, then there exist $x,y \in A$ such that $|x-y| \ge 1$, and that, therefore, the proposition above  cannot be false.

Is it in any way imaginable to give a direct proof of this proposition?

Answer (score 4):

$-1<x-y<1 \ \forall \ x,y\in A$ so $x<1+y,\ \forall \ x,y\in A \Rightarrow \sup A\leq 1+y ,\ \forall \ y\in A \Rightarrow y\ge \sup A -1, \forall \ y\in A\Rightarrow \inf A \ge \sup A-1$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\forall x,y\in A, |x-y|<1&\implies \sup_{x,y\in A}|x-y|\leq 1\\
&\implies \text{diam(A)}\leq 1\\
&\implies \sup(A)-\inf(A)\leq 1,
\end{align}
because if $A\subset \mathbb R$, then $$\sup(A)-\inf(A)\leq \text{diam}(A).$$